# Using Amazon Cognito Refresh Token to get new token in javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

When successfully logged in into the cognito user pool, I can retrieve **access token** and **id token** from the callback function as

```
onSuccess: function (result) {
    var accesstoken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()
    var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken
}
```

But how can I retrieve the **refresh token**? And how can I get a new token using this refresh token. I didnot find any clear answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `result.getRefreshToken().getToken()` for that.
The success callback takes `CognitoUserSession` object i.e. `result` as a parameter which exposes `getRefreshToken` method to retrieve refresh token.

Refer this link for Cognito JavaScript SDK documentation -

https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Not sure if I clearly understand your second question, but Use case 32 in above link might help you in dealing with it.

Comment: Thank you for that. Since the idToken expires every 1 hour, I want to use the Refresh Token to request for a new token whenever the idToken expires. Now I have got the refresh token from getRefreshToken, how can I initiate the process using Javascript?

Comment: Oh ok. I think the Use Case 32 in the above link then fits perfectly for this purpose. It has code in JS for that, you can use that as it is.

Comment: Just what I needed!! Thanks a lot!